# How to used chunked dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a recommendation project. The original dataset is large for my computer so I made it with smaller data. It works with smaller data but I couldn't integrate it to whole data. The cosine sim matrix comes differently in every chunk. I am not sure about how to find largest scores and their indexes in main dataframe. Anyone has idea?

## Read the data in chunks

```
data = pd.read_csv("books_with_blurbs.csv", chunksize=5000)
```

## **It calculetes the cosine sim scores**

```
def calculate_cosine_sim(dataframe):

    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    dataframe['Blurb'] = dataframe['Blurb'].fillna('')
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(dataframe['Blurb'])
    cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
    return cosine_sim
```

## It takes the title of book which we want to find similar books to it. It finds the similarity score based on the cosine similarity score and suggests the most similar 10 books (except itself)

```
def content_based_recommender(title, cosine_sim, dataframe):

    indices = pd.Series(dataframe.index, index=dataframe["Title"])
    indices = indices[~indices.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
    book_index = indices[title]
    similarity_scores = pd.DataFrame(cosine_sim[book_index], columns=["score"])
    book_indices = similarity_scores.sort_values("score", ascending=False)[1:11].index
    return dataframe['Title'].iloc[book_indices], similarity_scores
```

Comment: What do you mean "The cosine sim matrix comes differently in every chunk" ? [tour], [ask], [mre].